# Tesseract doesn't recognize characters(numbers)

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read a water level from a photo file(jpg or png).

but Tesseract does not read any of character at all even I cut the all the unnecessary area of photo.

I put a print function at the end of the code to see recognized number, but nothing appeared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaO00.jpg)

Here is the photo I have and under neath is the Python code.

```
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

image = cv2.imread ("water002.jpg")
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.Canny(image, 300, 350)

filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang=None)
#os.remove(filename)

print(text)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is there any tip to let Tesseract to read the level or any other method?